# show interstitial ads every time on screen revisit?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, react-navigation

When I visit a specific page interstitial ads come but when I revisit that specific page ad ad don't appear again.I am using firebase admob. This console.log is printed for every visit.

```
showAd = () => {
    if (advert.isLoaded()) {
        console.log('hi')
        advert.show();
    }
}

render(){
return(
 <View>
  <NavigationEvents
  onWillFocus={payload => this.showAd()}     
  />  
 </View>
)
```

Comment: Since console.log is printed for every visit, then the onWillFocus is working, your real issue is admob shows ad just once on ios I believe, correct me if I'am wrong.